# Azure DataBricks compute limited to 0 - why?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I am trying to do a tutorial for DataBricks and am trying to create a single node cluster, however whatever I do it just will not work. I'm pretty sure I'm on a pay-as-you-go subscription and the limit should be 10.

Whichever compute I select, I get this error:
[image]

with this message:

```
This account may not have enough CPU cores to satisfy this request
Estimated available: 0, requested: 4
Learn more about CPU quota.
```

When I've gone to up my limit it says that the limit is 0/10 so I should have 10 avaliable?

Please can someone else me with this. Thanks

Comment: you may have a limit on the instance types as well, not only on cores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First confirm your subscription is pay-as-you-go or not. If not upgrade, it**

1. Sign in to the  **Azure portal**
2. Navigate to  **Subscriptions**  and then select your subscription.
3. In overview under Offer you will find `pay-as-you-go`.

After this if it is `pay as you go` subscription you can follow below procedure to **Increase Azure Databricks Cluster vCPU Cores Limits**

1. Go to Azure Portal  > Clik in Search Resource Field> Type in “help” > Choose “Help + support”

[image]

2. At the top of the page , select “**Create a support request**” and fill the below information.

- **Summary**: Services and subscription limits (quotas)
- **Issue type** : Technical
- **Subscription**: choose your subscription
- **Service**: My services
- **Service Type**: Databricks
- **Resource**: select your resource
- **Problem Type**: cluster
- **Proble subtype**: select “Compute-VM (cores-vCPUs) subscription limit increases”

After selecting all the required fields, click “**Next**”.

[image]

3. In the “**Additional Details**” tab, click the link “**Provide details**” to bring the “**Quota details**” blade window to the right. Then, in the window:

- **Deployment model**: Select “Resource Manager”.
- **Location**: Select your location(s). Please note that you can request quota increases for multiple locations at one time.
- **Quotas**: Select the VM series that you want to increase the quota. Please note that you can request quota increases for multiple VM series at one time
- **New vCPU Limit**: Input the new quota that you want to increase up to

After filling in all the required information, click “**Save and continue**”.

[image]

after this select the Support format you want

[image]

4. Now **Next: Review + create >>**.